# How to build a List from Realtime database and update ListView in Flutter when data changes?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I have a list of users with their score, and I want to build a live leaderboard whenever any score changes or new user is added in ranks. In flutter's firebase_database SDK, there are methods for `onChildAdded`, `onChildChanged`, but what if I want to build this leaderboard where some users exist before the start of the competition and they have some score. How can I create a realtime leaderboard?
My basic code for now.

Function defined in `user` provider.

```
Stream getAllUsers() {
    return rtdb.child('ranks').orderByChild('score').onValue;
  }
```

Leaderboard.dart

```
import 'package:dating_app/providers/user.dart';
import 'package:dating_app/widgets/loader.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LeaderBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LeaderBoardState createState() => _LeaderBoardState();
}

class _LeaderBoardState extends State<LeaderBoard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).getAllUsers(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(!snapshot.hasData){
            return Loader();
          }else{
            print(snapshot.data);
            return Text('Hello World');
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> what if I want to build this leaderboard where some users exist before the start of the competition and they have some score

When you attach your listener, the `onChildAdded` is called for every existing child node that matches at the location straight away.

From the documentation on [listening for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events):

> `onChildAdded()`  Retrieve lists of items or listen for additions to a list of items. This **callback is triggered once for each existing child** and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path.